# Sort an array of objects in typescript?

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript

How do I sort an array of objects in TypeScript?

Specifically, sort the array objects on one specific attribute, in this case `nome` ("name") or `cognome` ("surname")?

```
/* Object Class*/
export class Test{
     nome:String;
     cognome:String;
}

/* Generic Component.ts*/
tests:Test[];
test1:Test;
test2:Test;

this.test1.nome='Andrea';
this.test2.nome='Marizo';
this.test1.cognome='Rossi';
this.test2.cognome='Verdi';

this.tests.push(this.test2);
this.tests.push(this.test1);
```

thx!

Comment: What have you tried?  Please show the code that you've tried, and we can suggest how to fix it.

Answer (score 76):

Simplest way for me is this:

Ascending:

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => (a.propertyToSortBy < b.propertyToSortBy ? -1 : 1));
```

Descending:

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => (a.propertyToSortBy > b.propertyToSortBy ? -1 : 1));
```

---

In your case,
Ascending:

```
testsSortedByNome = tests.sort((a, b) => (a.nome < b.nome ? -1 : 1));
testsSortedByCognome = tests.sort((a, b) => (a.cognome < b.cognome ? -1 : 1));
```

Descending:

```
testsSortedByNome = tests.sort((a, b) => (a.nome > b.nome ? -1 : 1));
testsSortedByCognome = tests.sort((a, b) => (a.cognome > b.cognome ? -1 : 1));
```

Comment: Hi, can we use a parameter while specifying the name of the prameter? like you have done a.name, can we do a.(some parameter which has the prop name)?

Comment: One of the greatest answers I've ever read here. Worked like a charm!!!

Comment: where are the types as in `typescript`?

Comment: Yes @Timo this would work in ts

Answer (score 55):

It depends on what you want to sort. You have standard *sort* funtion for *Array*s in JavaScript and you can write complex conditions dedicated for your objects. f.e

```
var sortedArray: Test[] = unsortedArray.sort((obj1, obj2) => {
    if (obj1.cognome > obj2.cognome) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (obj1.cognome < obj2.cognome) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Comment: this is just a small example, my array is composed of not less than 20 elements

Comment: I guess that you do not understand function passed as argument of sort method. The function always has two arguments (the same type what objects in your array) and it shows how to sort your array. In my example, size of array does not matter. Array may has two or one thousand elements. Sorting will be by comparison element by function (obj1, obj2) => { //..comparing } every time

Comment: You can also use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead of the multiple ifs: `(obj1, obj2) => obj1.cognome.localeCompare(obj2.cognome)`

Answer (score 18):

```
    const sorted = unsortedArray.sort((t1, t2) => {
      const name1 = t1.name.toLowerCase();
      const name2 = t2.name.toLowerCase();
      if (name1 > name2) { return 1; }
      if (name1 < name2) { return -1; }
      return 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
this.tests.sort(t1,t2)=>(t1:Test,t2:Test) => {
    if (t1.nome > t2.nome) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (t1.nome < t2.nome) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

have you tried sth like this?

Comment: how to implement something as generic as the size of my array varies periodically?

Comment: it sorts all list, if list size changes, sorted array size will change as well

Answer (score 6):

```
[{nome:'abc'}, {nome:'stu'}, {nome:'cde'}].sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.nome < b.nome)
    return -1;
  if (a.nome > b.nome)
    return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a function with a generic type:

```
const sortArrayOfObjects = <T>(
  data: T[],
  keyToSort: keyof T,
  direction: 'ascending' | 'descending' | 'none',
) => {
  if (direction === 'none') {
    return data
  }
  const compare = (objectA: T, objectB: T) => {
    const valueA = objectA[keyToSort]
    const valueB = objectB[keyToSort]

    if (valueA === valueB) {
      return 0
    }

    if (valueA > valueB) {
      return direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1
    } else {
      return direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1
    }
  }

  return data.slice().sort(compare)
}
```

Now if you use the function to sort array of objects, you can specify the object attribute you want to sort by.

```
const array = [
  { id: 2, name: "name2" },
  { id: 1, name: "name1" },
  { id: 3, name: "name3" }
];

const sortedArray = sortArrayOfObjects(array, "id", "ascending")

console.log(sortedArray)
//sorted ascending by id
// [
//   { id: 1, name: "name1" },
//   { id: 2, name: "name2" },
//   { id: 3, name: "name3" }
// ]
```

Using generic type and 'keyOf T' as type of attribute helps us to select only available object attributes, in this case, "id" and "name".
[typescript helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onwrv.png)

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sortarrayofobjects-obovd?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 2):

I often need to sort on a single field in a data set result, say `Id` and the shortest way of writing that is this

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.Id - b.Id)
    .forEach(row => {
           //something with row
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [110,5,72,14,12]
```

**Ascending Order Sort**

```
arr.sort(( a, b ) => a > b ? 1 : -1 )
```

**Descending Order Sort**

```
arr.sort(( a, b ) => a < b ? 1 : -1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method.

```
let sortedArray: Array<ModelItem>;
sortedArray = unsortedArray.slice(0);
sortedArray.sort((left, right) => {
    if (left.id < right.id) return -1;
    if (left.id > right.id) return 1;
    return 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular 7 and I tried pipe but didn't work and I tried this and got the output right.

let array of objects be in object result

```
results:any ={
 "providers": [
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "error": {
      "success": true,
      "message": "completed"
    },
    "quote_id": "BA503452VPC0012790",
    "quotes": {
      "comprehensive": {
        "premiumBreakup": {
          "premium": "17398.0",
        }
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Fi",

    "error": {
      "success": true,
      "message": "completed"
    },
    "quotes": {
      "comprehensive": {
        "premiumBreakup": {
          "premium": "27957.00"              
        }
      },
    }
  },
]
}
```

On clicking sort function

```
<button class="t-sort-optn" (click)="sortByPremium()">Premium</button>
```

To sort based on the premium value

```
sortByPremium(){
    var items = this.results.providers;
    console.log("Array",items);
    items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.quotes.comprehensive.premiumBreakup.premium - b.quotes.comprehensive.premiumBreakup.premium;
    });
    console.log("Array Sorted",items)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me

```
.sort((a, b) => {
  const a2 = a as unknown as Type;
  const b2 = b as unknown as Type;
  if (a2.something > b2.something) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (a2.something < b2.something) {
    return -1;
  } 

  return 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it more both readable and reusable, we have created a helper function:

```
export const by = <T>(attribute: keyof T) => {
  return (one: T, two: T) => {
    if (one[attribute] < two[attribute]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (one[attribute] > two[attribute]) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  };
};
```

Then we can use it like this:

```
const users = [ /* items here */ ];
const sorted = users.sort(by('name'));
```

Answer (score -3):

consider your array as myArray,

```
myArray.sort(( a, b ) => a > b ? 1 : -1 )
```

Comment: This should have been `myArray.sort(( a, b ) => a > b ? 1 : -1 )`