# Palantir typescript order rows and filter

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have already created a function that allows me to have a table obtained through groupby and aggregation function. Since the column I have grouped has so many values, I would like to sort descending the rows (by the "percentage" column, created by division of 2 columns) and then keep only the first 5 rows.

This I would like to do in TypeScript, perhaps by appending it under the groupby function, if possible.

Thank u!!!

Output example:

| column1 | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.75 |
| 2 | 0.65 |
| 3 | 0.63 |
| 4 | 0.61 |
| 5 | 0.55 |

Code example:

```
export class funzione1 {
     @Function()
        public async test1(object1: ObjectSet<object1>):
            Promise<TwoDimensionalAggregation<string>> {
                const numerators = await object1.groupBy(e => e.column1.topValues())
                                        .sum(e => e.column2);
                const denominators = await object1.groupBy(e => e.column1.topValues())
                                        .sum(e => e.column3);
        return this.divideTwoDimensional(numerators, denominators);
    }

    private divideTwoDimensional(numerators:TwoDimensionalAggregation<string>,
                             denominators: TwoDimensionalAggregation<string>):
                             TwoDimensionalAggregation<string> {

        const percentage = numerators.buckets.map((bucket, i) => {
           const numerator = bucket.value;
           const denominator = denominators.buckets[i].value;
            if (denominator === 0) {
                return { key: bucket.key, value: 0 };
            }
            return { key: bucket.key, value: numerator / denominator }
        });

        return { buckets: percentage };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the buckets by their percentage, using the JavaScript [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function with a custom comparator. For example, here the helper function `sortBucketsByValue2D` uses this to sort the buckets by their percentage value:

```js
import { Function, TwoDimensionalAggregation, BucketKey, BucketValue } from "@foundry/functions-api";
import { Objects, object1 } from "@foundry/ontology-api";

export class funzione1 {
    @Function()
    public async test1(object1: ObjectSet<object1>):
        Promise<TwoDimensionalAggregation<string>> {
        const numerators = await object1.groupBy(e => e.column1.topValues())
            .sum(e => e.column2);
        const denominators = await object1.groupBy(e => e.column1.topValues())
            .sum(e => e.column3);
        
        const withPercentage = divideTwoDimensional(numerators, denominators);
        return sortBucketsByValue2D(withPercentage, 'desc');
    }
}

const divideTwoDimensional = (
    numerators: TwoDimensionalAggregation<string>,
    denominators: TwoDimensionalAggregation<string>
): TwoDimensionalAggregation<string> => {
    const percentage = numerators.buckets.map((bucket, i) => {
        const numerator = bucket.value;
        const denominator = denominators.buckets[i].value;
        if (denominator === 0) {
            return { key: bucket.key, value: 0 };
        }
        return { key: bucket.key, value: numerator / denominator }
    });

    return { buckets: percentage };
}

/**
 * Sort buckets of a 2D aggregation by their value in the specified order
 * 
 * Example input 1:
 * { buckets: [
 *   { key: { min: "2022-01-01", max: "2022-12-31" }, value: 456 },
 *   { key: { min: "2021-01-01", max: "2021-12-31" }, value: 123 },
 *   { key: { min: "2023-01-01", max: "2023-12-31" }, value: 789 },
 * ]}
 * 
 * Example output 1:
 * { buckets: [
 *   { key: { min: "2021-01-01", max: "2021-12-31" }, value: 123 },
 *   { key: { min: "2022-01-01", max: "2022-12-31" }, value: 456 },
 *   { key: { min: "2023-01-01", max: "2023-12-31" }, value: 789 },
 * ]}
 * 
 * Example input 2:
 * { buckets: [
 *   { key: 17, value: 456 },
 *   { key: 21, value: 123 },
 *   { key: 23, value: 789 },
 * ]}
 * 
 * Example output 2:
 * { buckets: [
 *   { key: 21, value: 123 },
 *   { key: 17, value: 456 },
 *   { key: 23, value: 789 },
 * ]}
 */
function sortBucketsByValue2D<K extends BucketKey, V extends BucketValue>(
    buckets: TwoDimensionalAggregation<K, V>,
    order: 'asc' | 'desc' = 'asc'
): TwoDimensionalAggregation<K, V> {
    return {
        // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
        buckets: buckets.buckets.sort(({ value: v1 }, { value: v2 }) => {
            // These are be either numbers, timestamps or localdates which can be compared like this
            return (order === 'desc' ? -1 : 1) * (v1.valueOf() - v2.valueOf());
        }),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `percentage` list; it's simply an array of objects with a key/value structure like:

```
{
  key: "bucketKey",
  value: .5
}
```

So you can sort this list of objects as you would any other [list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311121/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-typescript).

Similarly, once sorted, you can use the [native array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array) `slice` method to return the first `n` elements of the array.

If you do this between creating the `percentage` array and the `return` statement where you add the `buckets` object, then you should get the desired result.

Comment: Can u kindly write me the whole code? I don't know where i can insert slice string into my script.