# How do you sort an array of objects by a given property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, sorting

Say you have an array of objects of the following type:

```
type Obj = {
  id: number,
  created: Date, 
  title: string
}
```

How would you sort by a given property without tripping up over the type system? For example:

```
const numberSorted = objArray.sortBy("id");
const dateSorted = objArray.sortBy("created");
const stringSorted = objArray.sortBy("title");
```

Comment: Have you tried? Which problems did you come across?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I've looked over the Array.prototype.sort() docs and came up with the following `sort((a,b) => a[property] > b[property] ? 1 : -1)`. IMO, this is verbose, so I was hoping from something a little slicker.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no slicker way, not built-in to Javascript at least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an array of objects in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311121/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-typescript)

Comment: Lots of npm packages are available for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

For example:

```
objArray.sort((a, b) => {
    // Some code for comparison
});
```

Learn more about the sort function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function like

```
function sortBy<T, V>(
        array: T[],
        valueExtractor: (t: T) => V,
        comparator?: (a: V, b: V) => number) {

  // note: this is a flawed default, there should be a case for equality
  // which should result in 0 for example
  const c = comparator ?? ((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1) 
  return array.sort((a, b) => c(valueExtractor(a), valueExtractor(b)))
}
```

which then could be used like

```
interface Type { a: string, b: number, c: Date }
const arr: Type[] = [
  { a: '1', b: 1, c: new Date(3) },
  { a: '3', b: 2, c: new Date(2) },
  { a: '2', b: 3, c: new Date(1) },
]
const sortedA: Type[] = sortBy(arr, t => t.a)
const sortedC: Type[] = sortBy(arr, t => t.c)
// or if you need a different comparison
const sortedX = sortBy(arr, t => t.c, (a, b) => a.getDay() - b.getDay())
```

This also works with nested properties within objects `t => t.a.b.c` or for cases where you need to derive the sort key further e.g. `t => t.a.toLowerCase()`